# Automatizar código Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente código que se repite según la clase .c más un número y .eq (según el orden en la lista), me gustaría automatizar este código sin tener que repetir una y otra vez lo siguiente:

```
if ($(".c1 .divItem").hasClass("selected")){
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 0 ).addClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 0 ).addClass( "circle_mark");
}
else{
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 0 ).removeClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 0 ).removeClass( "circle_mark");
}

if ($(".c2 .divItem").hasClass("selected")){
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 1 ).addClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 1 ).addClass( "circle_mark");
}
else{
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 1 ).removeClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 1 ).removeClass( "circle_mark");
}

if ($(".c3 .divItem").hasClass("selected")){
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "circle_mark");
}
else{
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( 2 ).removeClass( "selecte");
$( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( 2 ).removeClass( "circle_mark");
}
                               .
                               .
                               .
```

La idea es añadir la clase "selecte" y "circle_mark" a el elemento de la lista "x" si la clase es .c"x" 
Un saludo y garcias.

Comment: ¿Y el problema es?

Comment: Adrián márcala como respondida si crees que esta solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Construye un bucle

```
var num_repeticiones = 3;

for (i=1; i<=num_repeticiones; i++) {
  var name = ".c" + i + " .divItem";
  if ($(name).hasClass("selected")){
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( i-1 ).addClass( "selecte");
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( i-1 ).addClass( "circle_mark");
  } else {
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( i-1 ).removeClass( "selecte");
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( i-1 ).removeClass( "circle_mark");
  }
}
```

Comment: Este código no funcionaría, segun lo que ha mostrado de su código, no habría ninguna clase que fuera `.c0`, por lo que al inicio del bucle daría error

Comment: Bucle modificado para que empiece en 1, gracias por la observación.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciona a la perfección  añadí .eq(  i-1 ) para que el valor de .eq fuese igual que el de la clase "c+nº" y perfecto

Comment: Perfecto, lo edito para dejarlo marcado.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso puedes usar un bucle for:

```
var counter = 0;
var max; //Defina esta variable para definir el maximo en el que el bucle se ejecuta
for(var i = 1; i < max; i++) {
  if ($(".c"+i+" .divItem").hasClass("selected")){
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( counter ).addClass( "selecte");
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( counter ).addClass("circle_mark");
  } else {
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem" ).eq( counter  ).removeClass( "selecte");
    $( "ul" ).find( "li#index-item .divItem span a i" ).eq( counter  ).removeClass("circle_mark");
  }
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

No he testeado el codigo pero debería funcionar.

EDIT: Ahora si que deberia estar funcionar

Comment: alex55132 en el bucle debería ser 'i < max' en lugar de 'i > max' ya que es de recorrido ascendente y asi nunca entrará en el bucle ya que i nunca será mayor del máximo.

Comment: Cierto, modifico la respuesta, gracias @Carmen